# Finding pointwise limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

My question is where did "$1+r\cos$","$1+r\cot$" come from?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author has chosen polar coordinates centered at the point $(1,0)$ towards which the limit is being taken. In this system of coordinates,
$$x = 1 + r\cos \theta,\qquad y = r \sin\theta$$

They also use $$\cos \theta \equiv \cot \theta \times \sin\theta$$which is an identity.